# Java FileOutputStream - how to make file size show on file system immediately

Tags: java, io

When I write to file using any of the `OutputStream`s, in particular `FileOutputStream`, how do I make the file size show on the system without delay? Say I'm writing 100MB of data to a file over the course of 2 minutes in the form of `byte[]`s holding 10kB each, I don't see the file growing on my system (using `dir` in a Windows 7 command line, but I doubt that matters) while the program is running. After I kill the process or let it terminate on its own, the file size shows correctly. What I'd like to see is the file size growing dynamically during execution. Is this a file system issue or a Java issue?

Comment: It's neither of an fs issue or a Java issue, but a programming issue; fs operations are buffered, and you need to sync explicitly if you want the behaviour you intend. But syncing is expensive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your program, it is completely governed by the OS.

You *might* be able to get closer by closing and reopening the file on each buffer but that would slow down your program significantly. But there's no guarantee Windows is going to pay attention at a faster rate.

Consider that in a typical OS there are *thousands* of events happening every second, some of which could be reflected in the GUI or filesystem statistics.  If you required that all updates to the visible interface happened in real time the OS would spend all its time just updating things, most of which you don't really care about.

Your program executes in its own process, the OS has a bunch of threads monitoring things that have UI-visible attributes.  Those monitor processes wake up at short intervals but do not sit there spinning like an obsessed teenager waiting for a phone call.

If you need a realtime display of the file size you may have to add a window to your program that displays the file. This is known as a "progress bar" or "progress display".

In summary, the OS will never give you instantaneous real-time filesize numbers.  If you really, really have to have this you must provide it yourself.

Comment: I understand that it won't give me real-time numbers, but I'm surprised I don't see any changes even after several minutes. Thank you for your answer!